# jQuery UI Radio Button set line Breaks

Tags: jqueryi-ui-buttonset

when I am using two button sets, they do not display on same line. Is there a way to display both of these on the same line? Here is my code

html:

```
<div id="view">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Regular</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Investments</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">All</label>
</div>


<div id="lod">
<input type="radio" id="lod_S" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Summary</label>
<input type="radio" id="lod_D" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Detail</label>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#view,#lod').buttonset();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default styling for `div` elements causes one to be below the other. You can substitute `span` here.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh4F4/1/)

---

Or use CSS to change the styling of your divs:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #view, #lod {
        display: inline;
    }

</style>
```